# Error (400) Bad Request when attempting to connect to Sabre API

Tags: vb.net, sabre

I am trying to connect to the Sabre API using  the following code:

```
Dim u As String = "https://developer.sabre.com/io-docs/call-api"

' Create the web request  
request2 = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(u), HttpWebRequest)

' Get response  
response2 = DirectCast(request2.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

' Get the response stream into a reader  
reader2 = New StreamReader(response2.GetResponseStream())

' Console application output  

' MsgBox(reader.ReadToEnd())
Response.Write(reader.ReadToEnd())
```

However I am getting the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 49:
> Line 50:         ' Get response
> Line 51:         response2 = DirectCast(request2.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
> Line 52:
> Line 53:         ' Get the response stream into a reader

Comment: Can you share what are you trying to accomplish? Because if I go to the URL: https://developer.sabre.com/io-docs/call-api. -> I get: "There was an issue with your form submission."

Comment: i want to call an api the link i used its the link that it gives me when i test the api online

Comment: also i tried and changed my code still the same result i just want a way to call the api it doesnt have to be like my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not referencing the correct Sabre API endpoints. I would recommend looking at the .Net Sabre API Code Sample for reference information.

https://github.com/SabreDevStudio/SACS-DotNet

Comment: thanks i know my code is wrong and i did see that project before i didnt understand it because its very difficult that is why i need a simpler code thanks for your comment

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to go through the REST basics: https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_basics

There you have the different environment URLs, how to create sessions, and how to start consuming the REST APIs, same works for SOAP APIs.

The process on how to actually call each service will depend on the language, since you seem to be using VB.NET here you have 2 guides I found.

1. Using the REST Services with .NET (Microsoft.com)
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819168.aspx
2. Consuming a Json WebService from a C# or VB Application (Codeproject.com)
   https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233698/Consuming-a-Json-WebService-from-a-Csharp-or-VB-Ap

Comment: thanks bro i already did it and successfully connected to the API